# How can i download file inside app folder ?[ after packaging ]

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

This is my current folder structure[before packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNjY.png)  
WRM_80.. is my downloaded folder.

I have these two lines of code inside index.js  to download and show html in my electron window

```
fs.createReadStream('./Report.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: './'+folderName }));
LoginWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}./`+folderName+`/t01s01q01.html`);
```

in development mode its working fine, file downloaded inside the same folder where my index.js exists. But after packaging the app file is downloading outside app folder. Packaged folder structure is given below  WRM_80.. is my downloaded folder.
[after packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hip0s.png)

That's why I can not load that downloaded file into window. How can  I download file inside app folder? If that is not possible, how can I load external file from resources\app location ?

Comment: I don't see a difference in the images

Comment: @Zeokav please see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By referencing the directory as `./folder_name` you are essentially telling the application to download to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). In this case, the working directory is the folder that the program is contained in. While developing and using the `electron` command, the working directory is the root of your application. However once installed and running as a `.exe`, the working directory changes to the location of the executable.

To solve this problem, do not use the current working directory. Instead use the user / application data folder to store this information. It is not only a consistent location across development and deployment, but it is also the semantically correct place to store application data.

In Electron you can get the path to the application data folder for your app with:

```
const {app} = require('electron');
app.getPath('userData')
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
var userData = app.getPath('userData');
fs.createReadStream(`${userData}/Report.zip`).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: `${userData}/${folderName}` }));
LoginWindow.loadURL(`file://${userData}/${folderName}/t01s01q01.html`);
```

Comment: Thank you a Lot. That solved my problem. I also tried to solve it in another way and its also working fine.
 fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(`${__dirname}`,"Report.zip")).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: path.resolve(`${__dirname}`,folderName)}));              LoginWindow.loadURL(path.resolve(`${__dirname}`,folderName,'t01s01q01.html'));

Comment: Correct you can use `path.resolve` to get it working, but using the user data folder is a best practice. It gives a reliable location about "extra" data downloaded/used by your app apart from the core application which is in the install location.

Comment: Thanks again :) it will help. I am facing another issue after making win installer it comes with Trojan gen 2 virus in node module folder. i have to make an installer and give it to the client , I am in nightmare brother, how can i stay away from trojan gen 2 from installer files ?

Comment: Check which file is being reported and see if it is a legit node module. Otherwise it might be a false positive, so notify the AV company you used to detect it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004014/how-can-i-deploy-trojan-free-installer-for-electron-app

This is the file for which i am getting trojan gen two